# Change folder names in Joomla site

Tags: joomla1.5

I'm trying to change some folder names in a Joomla (1.5.23) website to better define what they contain. Everything I find refers to changing template names but in the admin panel I don't see anything named "templates".

So far I've been able to make all my changes by directly editing the files in the database but I can't find how to change a folder name. I tried changing it in the category manager and published it but still uses the old folder names.

Any direction would help at this point.

Answer (score 0):

From the Admin, under Extensions, you'll see Template Manager.  It displays your available templates based on folders in the \templates folder, and uses the templateDetails.xml within that folder for the admnin form.

Your best bet is to simply copy one of those folders, makes changes in the templateDetails.xml files (so you that you'll see a different name in the admin), and further investigate how it works from the copied version.